# Throw '&' String Url on Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to call url from Oracle stored procedure.

```
/* Formatted on 11/10/2016 19:04:58 (QP5 v5.185.11230.41888) */
DECLARE
   req     UTL_HTTP.req;
   resp    UTL_HTTP.resp;
   VALUE   VARCHAR2 (1024);
BEGIN
   req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://11.123.33.32:8002/Cool/value?car=Ferrari&Home=California');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
   resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response (req);

   LOOP
      UTL_HTTP.read_line (resp, VALUE, TRUE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (VALUE);
   END LOOP;

   UTL_HTTP.end_response (resp);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body
   THEN
      UTL_HTTP.end_response (resp);
END;
/
```

But it cannot read '&' string on oracle, how am I supposed to call an URL in a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ref_urlencode.asp).

**URL encoding** replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits.
So you can replace the `&` with equivalent 'safe' version `%26`.

Thus, your url would become

`'http://11.123.33.32:8002/Cool/value?car=Ferrari%26Home=California'`

meaning, you just replace 1 line in your code

`req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://11.123.33.32:8002/Cool/value?car=Ferrari&Home=California');`

becomes

`req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://11.123.33.32:8002/Cool/value?car=Ferrari%26Home=California');`

Comment: @AmirRachman Just replace 1 line in your code  with the one that I have provided. e.g. `req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://11.123.33.32:8002/Cool/value?car=Ferrari%26Home=California');` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
set define off;
```

before your code block should solve problem with reading `&`. Then execute whole as a script.

Comment: I've put this one on the top of the line, but the seems not working

Comment: Currently I'm using toad for the client

Comment: @AmirRachman http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/142538/ here you have link how to turn it off in TOAD. Interpreting `&` is property of client tool not the Oracle itself.